# C#: что производительнее?

Tags: c#, datetime, производительность

Есть текущая дата: `DateTime.Now;`

С точки зрения производительности, что выгоднее использовать:

```
1. DateTime.Now.ToString();
2. DateTime.Now.Year + "." + DateTime.Now.Month + "." ... и т.д. ?
```

Меня этот вопрос заинтересовал потому, что C# делает "кучу" вещей в методе `ToString`, например, в формат приводит по умолчанию (и прочие разные вещи из сборки `Globalization`). Это я узнал из *ANTS Memory Profiler*.

Comment: 1) Почему вас беспокоит этот вопрос? У вас есть основания полагать, что этот код может стать узким местом? 2) Вы пробовали измерять производительность самостоятельно?

Comment: Если у вас есть профайлер, то самый простой способ узнать что производительнее - это использовать его

Comment: Каждый вопрос о производительности **должен** сопровождаться объяснением, в чём узкое место. Экстремальная производительность достигается переписыванием программы на ассемблер, но от этой «оптимизации» отказываются даже авторы ядра операционной системы (и не только Windows).

Comment: @VladD, ну насчет "экстремальной производительности приложений написанных на ассемблере" - если сравнивать с C/C++ - оно очень-очень спорно. Верно это только для крошечных кусочков кода на ассемблере, написанных вовсе не за раз, а путем долгих и мучительных экспериментов-переборов. При большом же объеме кода, компилятору гораздо проще проанализировать и выдать максимально производительный исполняемый код, нежели даже очень опытному и постоянно помнящему многие нюансы ассемблерщику. Написать медленный код на ассемблере - это довольно легко :)

Comment: Ну, написание кода на ассемблере не означает отказ от применения оптимизатора с последующей ручной дошлифовкой. В любом случае, любой код можно скомпилировать в ассемблер, а значит, на ассемблере _можно_ получить ту же производительность. Или лучше. Вопрос того, какой ценой, оставим за рамками рассмотрения. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз уж вас заинтересовала производительность `DateTime` (например, вы очень часто пишете таймштампы в лог), то в первую очередь нужно использовать `DateTime.UtcNow` -- сам по себе [он *сильно* быстрее](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clrperfblog/2009/09/08/computing-time-in-net/).

Что касается `ToString()` против конкатенации: в данном случае конкатенация оказывается *немного* быстрее, так что в любом случае стоит использовать ее, а лучше `string.Format()` (спасибо @devEugene за напоминание).

Вопрос в том, кто кого "переборет" :).

Вообще такие вещи проверяются легко самостоятельно: консольное приложение, миллион итераций, `Stopwatch` и режим Release в помощь. Для более точного бенчмаркинга лучше использовать [более подходящие средства](https://github.com/PerfDotNet/BenchmarkDotNet).

У меня получилось вот что (1 000 000 итераций):

DateTime.Now.ToString() -- 0.9259747

DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() -- 0.8422381

DateTime.Now + string.Format -- 0.6951314

DateTime.UtcNow + string.Format -- 0.6167482

Comment: Добавлю только, что сравнение производительности может быть разным в разных версиях компилятора, с разной битностью системы и т. д.

Comment: Не совсем согласен с высказыванием: "в данном случае конкатенация оказывается немного быстрее". Смотря как написать конкатенацию, если постоянно обращаться к свойству .Now, то не быстрей, а если сделать DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; и потом dt.Year + "" и т.д., то тогда да, но также при использовании += стоит помнить, что строки - immutable! И вообще забудьте про конкатенацию, есть интерполяция строк(C#6) или string.Format().

Comment: А еще напомните, что при использование DateTime.Now.ToString() можно задать формат, и если вызвать просто без формата - то вернется строка с учетом текущего формата даты (MM/dd/yyyy, dd.MM.yyyy, etc.) как было замечено в вопросе используется Globalization, а при конкатенации потом будут, возникать проблемы, либо в ночных билдах, либо при выгрузки на прод инваирмент и т.д. Так что не нужно городить костылей...

Comment: Пример очень простой, вы делаете сайт с выгрузкой некой инфы и фильтром к ней по дате, в формате (dd.MM.yyyy), она обратно идет на сервер и парсится, вроде все ок, отдаем заказщику за бугор, при парсинге возникает эксепшн и он пишет вам, что ничего не работает!

Comment: А ничего что у ToString и конкатецации форматы разные?

Answer (score 2):

Без тестов, навскидку такой код должен быть быстрее всего

```
// указать размер достаточный для строки, 
//но не меньше чем конечная строка.
var sb = new StringBuilder(4+1+2+1+2); 
var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
sb.Append(date.Year);
sb.Append('.');
sb.Append(date.Month);
sb.Append('.');
sb.Append(date.Day);
return sb.ToString();
```

StringBuilder создаст один буфер который потом вернет в виде строки. Никаких дополнительных аллокаций (как в случае с конкатенацией), никакого дополнительного парсинга (как в случае с Format), никаких культур и прочего оверхеда (как в случае с ToString).