# В чем практическая разница между двумя вариантами составления строк?

Tags: c#

1. `MessageBox.Show("Точка Х=" + Х + ", Точка Y=" + Y);`
2. `MessageBox.Show("Точка Х={0}, Точка Y={1}", X, Y);`

Comment: А вообще, я что-то не вижу в доке второй перегрузки для `MessageBox.Show`.

Comment: Я тоже. А так вообще, для трех строк нет разницы между форматом и плюсованием. Если их штук 50, тогда формат эффективнее.

Comment: К примеру, решарпер предлагает второй вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод интерполяции также склеивает то есть генерирует строку но как уже сказано эффективен при большом количестве выбираемых и обрабатываемых данных коллекций и т.д. Вот произведенные условия по производительности

[C#: что производительнее?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/506643/c-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5)

Answer (score 3):

Второй вариант более гибкий, так как позволяет отдельно сформировать форматную строку и стало быть вывести сообщение в более подходящем формате. В первом же варианте позиции значений жёстко фиксированы в коде.

Также вероятно первый вариант менее эффективен, из-за склеивания строк. Хотя могу ошибаться, т.к. с шарпом уже давно не работал.